# Make column NOT NULL with default values

Tags: sql-server

Is there one line query for changing nullable column to non-nullable with applying default values for null records. May be like

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ALTER COLUMN myColumn INT NOT NULL WITH VALUES
```

if it's not there then what could be the reason because we can use `WITH VALUES` with `ADD` column.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding a default value then it is obvious that the column cannot be NULL(*unless you add it explicitly*). So there is no point of adding it explicitly. You can simply do it like

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD CONSTRAINT DF_SomeName DEFAULT 0 FOR myColumn
```

And if your column presently allows NULL values and you are trying to make it NOT NULL then it means you are trying to alter the constraint of that column like

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ALTER COLUMN myColumn INT NOT NULL
```

Now your column needs a value and cannot be NULL.

Comment: I already have default value for that column, but I was curious to know if there is one liner

Comment: @Anonymous:- I have updated my answer. And it is obvious that if your column has a default value then it cannot be NULL so why to add it explicitly.

Comment: If someone explicitly tries to insert null, then?

Comment: @Anonymous:- Then you need to alter the column to NOT NULL as you are doing it. I don't think there is a one liner to do that if you are looking for that.